# Control youtube videos inside a webview present as a listview item

Tags: android, listview, video, webview, youtube

I'm trying to play multiple YouTube videos in a listview without showing a separate dialog/popup to play the videos.

I do understand there is a [Youtube SDK v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) for android, but are is only an option of showing youtube videos in a new fragment or a popup(lightboxMode). Also referencing [Youtube SDK example](http://createdineden.com/blog/2015/may/12/android-tutorial-how-to-integrate-youtube-videos-into-your-app/)

So, I have tried using a embedded Youtube url in a webview as an Listview item.(Accepting this might not be a good idea for scrolling)

But the issue is that when a video starts playing, the user has to manually pause the video to watch a second video.(First video keeps playing in the background).

How can we stop the youtube video playing in the first listitem when the second youtube video is played.

Here is the code Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("http://www.youtube.com/embed/dO1rMeYnOmM?&rel=0&fs=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&modestbranding=1&controls=0&autohide=1");
    arrayList.add("http://www.youtube.com/embed/dO1rMeYnOmM?&rel=0&fs=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&modestbranding=1&controls=0&autohide=1");

    YoutubeListAdapter youtubeAdapter = new YoutubeListAdapter(arrayList, this);
    listView.setAdapter(youtubeAdapter);
}
```

Adapter 
public class YoutubeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
Context context;

public YoutubeListAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList, Context context) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return arrayList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    viewHolder.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    viewHolder.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    viewHolder.webView.loadUrl(arrayList.get(i));


    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    private WebView webView;
}
```